# How to implement zooming using swiper latest version(11.0.6) in angular?

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I am trying to use zooming using swiper in angular, but couldn't find any reference. can you please give me some solution. Thanks.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NoticePostListComponent } from './notice-post-list/notice-post-list.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NoticePostComponent } from './notice-post/notice-post.component';
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register();

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: NoticePostListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'post/:id',
    component: NoticePostComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NoticePostComponent,
    NoticePostListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ConsumerPopUpComponent,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    NgbModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class NoticeBoardModule { }
```

```
<swiper-container slides-per-view="1" pagination="true" loop="false">
  <swiper-slide *ngFor="let img of noticePost.attachments">
    <img [src]="img.s3ResourceUrl" height="200" width="340" alt="Random slide">
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

This is how i am using swiper.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to add zoom, please follow the below points!

1. When we need to add properties, we need to ensure they are kebab case.

html params

```
zoom-max-ratio="3"
zoom-min-ratio="1"
```

is the same as

```
...
zoom: {
   maxRatio: 3,
   minRatio: 3,
}
...
```

2. Ensure you have included the CSS for swiper zoom

css

```
@import 'swiper/css/zoom';
```

in my case:

```
@import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
```

3. The elements inside `*ngFor` or the slides, must be wrapper with a div with class `.swiper-zoom-container` this will ensure zoom works fine

html

```
  <swiper-container
    style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff"
    class="mySwiper"
    zoom-max-ratio="3"
    zoom-min-ratio="1"
    thumbs-swiper=".mySwiper2"
    space-between="10"
    navigation="true"
  >
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
        <img [src]="slide.image" />
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
```

Below is a working example for reference

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-54daor?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html,src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.scss,src%2Findex.html)